# Not a valid bookmark Microsoft Access 2016

Tags: ms-access-2016

Now i am using Microsoft Access 2016 and suddenly i can't open one of my tables.Its say "Not a valid bookmark".

After using compact and repair,that table is missing.

I can't export the database,That error is always.I have no idea why.

I was checked other answer and It doesn't make clue.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

That's a corruption issue. Running C&R is your only method to get it cleaned up.

So, revert to the latest backup, restore data otherwise somehow, or - if essential and valuable data are lost - contact a paid restore service.

A reputable service can be found [here](https://www.everythingaccess.com/accessdatabaserepair_info.asp).

Comment: I already try C&R,But after running,that error table is gone.Currently VB app,C# app and Asp.net app are using that database. Is the paid restore service is only chance? Is there any other thing i can try?

Comment: Thanks for u r answer.

Comment: There are no other tools or options.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you made a back up before C&R so whether or not you still have that trouble-table.

Create a brand new db.  Import into it everything from the problem db EXCEPT that trouble-table.    Sanity check that all this behaves ok.

Create another new db - and import into it only the trouble table.  It probably still won't open but it might.  If it does - export the data out to excel; create a new table in your other new db; and import the data back in.  If it does not open try another C&R with this new db file.  If still no joy I think you'll have to create a new table.

You'll want to try and determine how this happened - I rarely see a totally corrupt table.  A move to a new edition i.e. 2016 - if it is a big jump such as from 2003 - I have seen where things are less forgiving.  Be sure if this is multi user that the db application is split and every user has their own front end file - this is the primary cause of corruption these days.