# Criteria: Between #date# And #otherDate# cause Microsoft Access database to corrupt and then I get this error message: Unrecognized database format

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

In Microsoft Access, I made a simple query with criteria to list all entries in a table between two dates. It was working well for more than a year, but now I think I am facing a bug...

Between #2022-11-29# And #2023-01-2**6**# causes a bug that corrupts the database and then I get the error message: Unrecognized database format

Between #2022-11-29# And #2023-01-2**5**# causes no bug and no error message and I get the data

<#2022-11-29# causes no bug and no error message and I get the data

Any idea how we can find what is causing the bug and prevent database to get currupted?

Thank you!

I removed the data from shared folder and recreated the problem locally on one computer. Same issue...

*** UPDATE ***

I found this in the result when I query: <#2022-11-29#

[image: Screenshot]

I am trying to remove the entry but I always get the Invalid bookmark popup. any idea how to remove this line?

Comment: Maybe reinstall Access. I cannot replicate issue. I enter dates as you show and Access query designer changes them to mm/dd/yyyy structure.

Comment: I made an update to the post. Please have a look.

Comment: What is the field showing #Error? I am not familar with "Not valid bookmark" error.

Comment: Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54475152/not-a-valid-bookmark-microsoft-access-2016

Comment: consider taking just a small amount of the problematic data and trying to make a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example .  If you can replicate the problem then it might be a combination of data and structure.

Comment: Thanks all for your help! Im trying to export all data to excel, delete all records, and reimport back in Access table. The corrrupted data dont export to Excel so I have hope...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I fixed this:

I exported all the data I could to Excel from the corrumpted database and then removed problematic data in Excel manually.

I exported same data of the most recent backup in Excel too.

I merged all the data into excel. Verified the data manually and with formulas comparing differences between sheets.

I then deleted all the entries in Access tables.

I imported the data from Excel sheets to Access tables.

The problem seems to be gone.